# SQLite, SQL: Using UPDATE or INSERT accordingly

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

Basically, I want to insert if a given entry (by its primary key id) doesn't exist, and otherwise update if it does.  What might be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does sqllite not have `REPLACE` command ? Or `ON CONFLICT REPLACE` ?

Comment: Note that `REPLACE` resets any fields you're not explicitly setting in your query. Sadly there is no `ON CONFLICT UPDATE`...